# Virtaul host file for mass proxying does not work

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I'm trying to adapt the an example for mass proxy:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

`vhost.map` contains:

```
www.customer-1.com /www/customers/1
```

httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

# define the map file
RewriteMap vhost txt:/www/conf/vhost.map

# this does the file-based remap
RewriteCond ${vhost:%1} ^(/.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %1/docs/$1
```

Now, if I go to `www.customer-1.com`, nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong? Of course I restarted the server.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing happens'? Are there any error messages displayed? Are there any relevant messages in your log files ?

Comment: No error message is displayed! I'm just redirected to: `http://navigationshilfe1.t-online.de/dnserror?url=www.customer-1.com`, which means the site is not found (of course as it does not exist yet). I just want to test the mapping, and afaik the mapping should already take place to /www/customers/1 which should be shown in browser address line, regardless if it could be resolved?

Comment: @membersound Why would it be shown in the browser address line?  That only changes when you redirect.  You're not redirecting - are you intending to?  Can you clarify what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Sounds like your DNS is not set up correctly. The host names you want to test somehow have to point to your test server.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was confused. Yes of course it should not show in the browser as I do not want to redirect, just proxy. Anyhow the proxying does not take place, and logs do not contain any hints...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a DNS error. Ensure that www.customer-1.com correctly resolves to the IP address of the machine doing the proxying.